# re-scaling the values between given maximum and minimum, where max is positive and min is negative

Tags: python, perl, math, graph, statistics

I want the re-scale an array of values (both positive and negative floating point values), so that the values lies between say -5 to +5 or say -3 to +2. How can I scale it down. Is there any specific formula for it. I tried searching, but did not found anything that can deal with negative min value.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: perl or python would do

Comment: Are you looking for specific numbers to specific values or just a way to convert all the numbers to `-5<=x<=+5`

Comment: I want to convert all the numbers to -5<=x<=+5 , so that when I plot a line graph with this values, the graph does not change its shape, only the scale changes to -5<=x<=+5

Comment: A versatile formula has been described here:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281162/scale-a-number-between-a-range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to scale your data down is to determine the maximum value of your data (positive or negative) and use that to scale all the other data accordingly.

For example, if you had a maximum of 320 in your data

```
 320 / 320 * 5  => 5
 160 / 320 * 5  => 2.5
-160 / 320 * 5  => -2.5
```

So as a general equation

```
x / abs(maximum) * scale
```

Comment: Really good, simple solution for 'even' scaling (-5 to +5 in this case), but it doesn't cover the '-3 to +2' requirement.

Comment: That's cause in reality you can't do that, he wants to scale it such that the data would look the same on a data plot. In order to scale it to variable axis length, one of the sides would appear "stretched" compared to the other. You could scale it so that the data _looked_ the same but it would end up being offset by half the difference of the axis lengths.

Comment: You are correct. I read the post before there were many other comments. I took it literally as "Rescale my values between a user-defined min an max."

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this to map values onto a (0, 1) scale:

```
y = (x - xmin) / (xmax - xmin)
```

You can also use finite element shape functions:

```
y = h1*x1 + h2*x2
```

where

```
h1 = (z - 1)/2.0 for -1 <= z <= +1
h2 = (z + 1)/2.0 for -1 <= z <= +1
```

This maps your values onto a (-1, 1) scale.

Comment: but I want to have min value to be -ve not 0

Comment: The original values that you want to map onto the (-1,1) scale.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a linear interpolation/extrapolation formula to get the results you want.

Code:

```
def rescale(val, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max):
    return out_min + (val - in_min) * ((out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min))

print(rescale(4, 4, 20, 0, 100))  # => 0.0
print(rescale(12, 4, 20, 0, 100)) # => 50.0
print(rescale(20, 4, 20, 0, 100)) # => 100.0
print(rescale(0, 4, 20, 0, 100))  # => -25.0
```

Note that this code doesn't check your values against the min and max bounds supplied, hence it will extrapolate as in the last example. Modify it as you need.